# Operator not applicable to this operand type When filtering a table

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

i'm trying to filter a table with 2 different filters, so that when a button is pressed the only records displayed are those with a certain Job_ID and those with the Type 'Private'.
i have the following code:

```
if CBSearchType.Text = 'Private' then
begin
DBTravel.DataSource.DataSet.DisableControls;
            DBTravel.DataSource.DataSet.Filtered := False;
            DBTravel.DataSource.DataSet.Filter := ('Job_ID = '+edtAddJobID.Text) AND       ('Type = '+QuotedStr('Private'));
            DBTravel.DataSource.DataSet.Filtered := True;
            DBTravel.DataSource.DataSet.First;
            DBTravel.DataSource.DataSet.EnableControls;
end;
```

however when i try to compile the error message 'Operator not applicable to this operand type' is displayed, any suggestions?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter property must be a string

```
DBTravel.DataSource.DataSet.Filter := Format('(Job_ID =%s) AND (Type=%s)',[edtAddJobID.Text,QuotedStr('Private')]);
```

Comment: Job_ID seems to be numeric and edtAddJobID seems to be an edit field. For improved type safety and user input error handling, use string to Integer conversion, and then use the Integer value in the Format function using %d: `(Job_ID = %d) AND ...`

Comment: following the same code ive done the following change                                 
             DBTravel.DataSource.DataSet.Filter   := Format('(Job_ID =%s) AND (Mode =%s)',[edtAddJobID.Text,edtSearchMode.Text]);                                                               With Mode entries being string e.g 'Car','Train'. However when i run  the program and enter the Mode and press the button it says that arguments are of the wrong type, what is different?

Comment: When you compare a string field you must quote the string to compare try this : `DBTravel.DataSource.DataSet.Filter := Format('(Job_ID =%s) AND (Mode =%s)',[edtAddJobID.Text,QuotedStr(edtSearchMode.Text)]); `

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that `Filter` is a string. Hence, you have to give it a string.

```
'(Job_ID = ' + edtAddJobID.Text + ') AND (Type = ' + QuotedStr('Private') + ')';
```